# Migrating from Beta o365 API to v1.0 o365 API

Tags: office365, office365api

Hi Team, I am in the process of migrating our beta graph API  to production API. In beta API, when I call any function, I am able to get the required data, but when I call the same function using the Production API,  I get a different set of (lesser) data. I am not sure if both the APIs at the backend are speaking to the same system or do we need to make any configuration changes?
Also, I am looking for what are all the parameters are passed in the v1.0.

I am using beta API [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/findRooms(RoomList='user@hostname.edu') ] of O365 in beta API I am able to get the data, but according to production I am not able to get data I am using this endpoint for data https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/findRooms(RoomList='user@hostname.edu')

Thanks for your help,

Kailas Kakade

Answer (score 1):

Yes I also encountered same problem using below API I was not able to get attributes(userType, department) I was looking for so I did select query which return the attribute I queried. Hope this helps.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

SELECT QUERY:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,givenName,surname,userPrincipalName,id,mail,department,jobTitle,userType
```